# table cell indicater problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, accessoryview

in my application I have `UITableView` & i used

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
```

and when I scrolled this table then I get  multiple checkmark in multiple cell

please help me..

Comment: Can you post your code where are you setting the cell accessory view for better understanding your code.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the cell come from 2 ways:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = ... // The cell come from reuse queue.
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = ... // if reuse queue has no cell, then create an autoreleased cell
  } 

  // Configure cell by indexPath.
  // You should configure cell HERE.

}
```

Because your cell maybe come from reuse queue, it was configured. Obviously, you forget to re-configure those cells which come from reuse queue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this sample code on tableView's delegate method didSelectedRowAtIndexPath

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

```
    for(int iterator=0;iterator<3;iterator++)
    {

        UITableViewCell *eachCell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:iterator inSection:0]];
        [eachCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
        [eachCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [newCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
    [newCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
```